# An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use error occurs when using OleDbConnection in c#

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I am using access database in C#.

I have helper class called MdbLibrary.

In my application, multi thread calls open and close.

And it gives an error below:

```
An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use.  The RCW is in use on the active thread or another thread.  Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause corruption or data loss.
```

It always happen when closing the connection.

```
private OleDbConnection _Conn = null;

public void Open(string _strConnectionString)
{
    _Conn = new OleDbConnection(_strConnectionString);
    _Conn.Open();

    _Command = new OleDbCommand();
    _Command.Connection = _Conn;
    if (this.ConnectionTimeOut != 30)
        _Command.CommandTimeout = this.ConnectionTimeOut;
}

public void Close()
{
    _Conn.Close();  --> here i get an error.
}
```

Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use the Connection from different threads? Give any Thread its own connection and its own commands.

Comment: Please also implement the `IDisposable` pattern.

Comment: @Ralf Do you have any other workaround? It is slightly difficult to fix the help library.

Comment: @Arran What's it got to do with IDisposable? Any documentation that I could have a look at?

Comment: Give each thread its own Instance of the helper Library? But its not an other workaround. If the Helper Library explicitly allows to use the Connection from Different Thread i would call that one broken.

Comment: please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318781/how-do-i-deal-with-an-attempt-has-been-made-to-free-an-rcw-that-is-in-use-er

Comment: please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318781/how-do-i-deal-with-an-attempt-has-been-made-to-free-an-rcw-that-is-in-use-er