# How do I deal with "An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use. " Error

Tags: vb.net

I know this question might be duplicate questions but I have a problem and need a solution to overcome it.

I've made a project and used functions and Sub everywhere.

One of the function/Sub is like,

```
Public Sub ExecuteQuery(Xcn As OleDbConnection)
    Try
        If Xcn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Xcn.Close()
        Xcn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = Xcn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Xcn.Close()
    Catch e As Exception
        Throw e
    End Try
End Sub
```

I just use `executequery(con)` instead of writing whole sentence everytime.
Now the question is that I created a bw_worker and running a sub that includes small subs like I showed above asynchronously.

For example, A sub is that I run async like,

```
Private Sub RunCode()
    dim cmd as new oledbcommand("Select * from table",con)
    if con.state = ConnectionState.closed then con.open()
    execute reader stuff here
    if con.state = ConnectionState.Open then con.close()
    ExecuteQuery(con)
    cmd = new Oledbcommand("Select * from Table2",con)
    ExecuteQuery(con)
End Sub
```

I don't know if its good practice or not but now problem arises.
I am trying to create a loading screen for some time taking functions and subs so I referred this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/535081/Displayingplusanimatedplusgifpluswhilepluscodeplus) and faced the error.
**NOTE:** I understood the error it gives but I want to know a workaround if possible. Like something possible without changing a lot of code.

Comment: Why not show the code that throws the exception so we can help you?

Comment: You should keep you database objects local so you can control closing and disposing them with `Using...End Using blocks. In `RunCode` you will be executing some other command from another place because you have declared cmd locally.

Comment: Why are you trying (and failing) to use `.ExecuteNonQuery` with a Select statement?

Comment: Where do you add parameters to your commands? You are using Parameters not concatenating strings to build Sql statements. Yes?

Comment: I cringe whenever I see `If con.State = ` If your database objects are local you will never have to ask that question. Stepping off my soap box now. :-)

Comment: I have to agree with much of what @Mary said.  That code is rather crazy.  You're executing `SELECT` statements with no way to access their result sets and you're opening and closing a single connection all over the place.  You should be creating a connection, opening it, executing each query and getting their result sets, then closing the connection and discarding it.  Your `ExecuteQuery` method is bad for several reasons.

Comment: @Mary exception throws on `if con.state = ConnectionState.Open then con.close()` or whenever I close the connection like `xcn.close` The exception say that the connection that I am trying to close might be open and used in another thread. Closing it may occur data loss. Its kinda warning but later I get error like `connection was not closed.`--> For this connection error I open it, make the work done and immediately close it. It works well without error if executed directly and not in `bw.workasync`

Comment: @Mary Using block like Using `Con...` `...End Using`? Where shall I use it? In every sub like `executequery(xcn as OledbConnection)`?

Comment: @Mary No I just gave example. Actually I use query to Insert,update,delete. It was tough to write it so I just wrote a simple select query and I believe not to give code as it might get difficult for others to understand. And yes I use parameter and it works easily. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trans_Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = TransDate.Value`---> THis is how I write parameter after cmd command query and right after it in very next line I write `ExecuteQuery(con)` and it works fine.

Comment: @Mary So what do I do if I stop using `if con.state = ` statement? Sometimes in my project, if it gives exception and if connection state kept open then it gives error in next function/sub.is there any proper alternative? I also tried writing in finally but this helped me better so I continued with this. Give me best practice to write it,I'll try to follow you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ya I guessed that. I guess I have to change it at every place. And with it I also guess there might be no workaround to deal with the error except rectifying the open and close connections everywhere! right?

Comment: @Mary And Ya, cmd is declared globally and not locally. That's just I showed the what cmd is declared to.- Count it as my fault

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your database objects local they won't be open on another thread. Commands too. This code will demonstrate how to use Using blocks which will close and dispose of your database objects even if there is an error. Please no .AddWithValue. The .Add method forces you to name a datatype which will help with visually providing a clue that the datatype passed in matches. There are also several database reasons to use .Add. See https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/  and https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

It is okay to have a class level variable for the connection string so you don't have to type it all the time.

```
Private ConnString As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub RunCode()
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from table", con)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'reader stuff here
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay This might help

Comment: One more help, I understood whatever you said but assume that I want 1st row 1st column data from query. So I made a function name `GetData` It calls the data using data adapter/datareader and fetches the first data from it. Now I am not going to declare DataReader/Adapter again and again everywhere. So what shall I do for that?

Comment: It's worth noting that you don;t have to nest two `Using` blocks unless there's code between them. A single `Using` statement can create multiple objects separating them with commas. That means that the connection and command can be created with a single `Using` statement here. You'll still need a second `Using` statement for the data reader though, because you have to call `Open` on the connection in between.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've added some of my code Look after **EDIT**. Now these codes is like I am using it probably everywhere. Sometimes about a 20 times in a single class. What alternative can I do? I understood every thing you and @ Mary taught but how shall I change now? I'm ready to do the hard work. Just teach me with one satisfactory example.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Don't Show. Very Very thanx to give me a push. I am now changing and using `using` keyword everywhere. Thanx a lot Mary too. Please tell me anything more if you it that my be helpful. I read an article about connectionpool. Is it good?

Comment: @RitaShroff To get the first column of the first row use cmd.ExecuteScalar . You can assign the result to a single variable. Let's say you are retrieving an id that is of type Integer. Dim myID = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar) You will want to Dim your variable outside of the Using block otherwise it is only visible inside the block.

Comment: @RitaShroff Connection pooling is wonderful and comes for free with ADO.net. It is turned on by default for SQL Server and OleDB. It is just there; you don't need to do anything except be sure your connections are closed with a Using block so they can be returned to the pool.

Comment: @RitaShroff This thread has gone way beyond the scope of the original question. It will not be helpful to other users because the information presented is not germane to the question. Correct your code as we have suggested and when you have trouble, post new code with a new question.

Comment: @Mary Yes I made use of `Using` keyword Everywhere. And it worked like a charm for me. I am deleting the Edit part to make the question proper. Thanx again.