# Can I pass a parameter of an OledbCommand to other OledbCommand?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbcommand

This might be silly question but I need some solution in it.
I've done like

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Table1(Col1,Col2,Col3,Date) Values (1,'aa',101,?)"
cmd.Connection = con2
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", transdate)
ExecuteQuery(con2,cmd)
```

I wrote below code to avoid writing Using.. End Using everywhere.
Query runs fine if it has no parameter.

```
Private Sub ExecuteQuery(con as OledbConnection,cmd as OledbCommand)
Using con1 As New OleDbConnection(con.ConnectionString)
    Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(cmd.CommandText)
        cmd1.Connection = con1
        con1.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

It works fine with parameters when I write cmd under `Using` Block.
But as I said, I am avoiding writing `Using` everywhere.
But doing like this gives error -- **No Given values for one or more required parameters.**

Comment: Why, oh why would you avoid writing Using blocks. It is supposed to make your life easier. No more Close and Dispose code.

Comment: Keep your database objects local. Declare within a method as local variables. Use them within the method. Then Close and Dispose them in the same method. These objects can be using unmanaged code which the GC cannot collect. This makes Dispose important so the object can release the unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your ExecuteQuery because it's making a new command and losing the Parameters. Change it so that it uses the existing command you passed, and disposes it, or transfer the Parameters from your inbound command to the new one

```
Private Sub ExecuteQuery(con as OledbConnection, cmd as OledbCommand)
  Using con1 As New OleDbConnection(con.ConnectionString)
    Try
        cmd.Connection = con1
        con1.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Try
  End Using 
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteQuery(con as OledbConnection,cmd as OledbCommand)
  Using con1 As New OleDbConnection(con.ConnectionString)
    Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(cmd.CommandText)
        cmd1.Connection = con1
        ForEach p as Parameter in cmd.Parameters
          cmd1.Parameters.Add(p) 
        con1.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
    End Using
  End Using
End Sub
```

If you're looking for a way to make your db life easier check out Dapper or Entity Framework - you work with objects, it writes all the sql for you. This isn't a cessation of control (you still write the queries) it's delegating the boring aspects of executing your query, going through the results, digging out each text or int and assigning it to your user object's name or age..

If you get to a point where you don't want to write the SQLs either, use Entity Framework, as it can convert between your objects and the db automatically

Comment: I got your answer but can you give me small example.??
Also I have to use `Using` keyword.

Comment: Edited an example in

Comment: I was working like the example you given before but that won't work properly in `backgroundworker` so I am shifting with `Using` keyword. I am suggested to use `Using` and it works good executing query async

Comment: Check this link Please. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318781/how-do-i-deal-with-an-attempt-has-been-made-to-free-an-rcw-that-is-in-use-er/56319762?noredirect=1#comment99265563_56319762)

Comment: BackgroundWorker shouldn't have any effect on Using

Comment: `cmd1.Parameters = cmd.Parameters` This isn't working in using block. **Property parameters is readonly** .. _it's making a new command and losing the Parameters._ I understood this sentence.

Comment: Ya Bw isn't have any effect in Using block but writing like first `ExecuteQuery` block (Try..Catch one) in your answer gives error like **Another process still using connection. Data loss may occur**..

Comment: If another process is using the same connection, you should make a new one outside of your ExecuteQuery! I've posted an edit that creates a new connection inside the using (and I've also made an edit to copy the parameters out of the first query and into the second), but some of these questions you're asking now arent related to the original question above. You're causing yourself problems by adding multi threading and reusing things in non-thread-safe ways

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194281/discussion-between-rita-shroff-and-caius-jard).

Comment: Thank You. I removed 2nd `Using` i.e `Using cmd1` and it worked for me. Thanx a lot..

Comment: @CaiusJard You are passing in a Connection and a Command then creating another New Connection and Command. Now you have 4 objects floating around. Why not just pass the ConnectionString As String and the CommandText As String and only create the objects locally in the Sub? Also I would call your method NonQueryExecution or something to indicate not to send Select statement. I would make this a Function that returns Rows Affected.

Comment: I'm not passing anything; you wouldn't catch me using this abomination of a code pattern in one of my apps, but the OP is wedded to it, possibly by sunk-cost fallacy, this being just the latest in a line of questions on the topic. Don't worry about "objects floating around" - that's what the garbage collector is for; I don't consider it particularly more resource intensive to create a SqlCommand that is never used for anything other than a fancy data container for the command string and parameters collection; we're still only connecting one to the db.. I agree with all your points; it's a turd